# Is -mllrmat similar to mllr_transform

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to adapt my acoustic models for sphinx4 using MAP and MLLR. 
I do understand that I have to use the `mllr_solve` binary and the `bw` to do one iteration.

I'd like to know if using bw's `-mllrmat` option is equivalent to using the `mllr_transform` tool to apply the baseline means before the bw call.
In other words: Can I skip the `mllr_transform` step if I am using the `-mllrmat` option in `bw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, effect would be the same.